# Insert incoming data (and pk from 2nd table) into 1st table if true boolean value from 2nd table

Tags: mysql

This question is further to my previous question answered very well by @ypercube [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182789/insert-into-table-where-boolean-value-in-another-table-is-true/182808?noredirect=1#comment353020_182808)

I have been trying to work out the easiest way to ask the question without ambiguity, here I go...

I have data arriving from a sensor that contains a unique serial number and a data value. The sensor configuration along with its unique serial number is in a table called device which also contains other settings such as enabled or disabled.

I want to store the incoming data value into another table named datain along with the primary key from the device table.

I am currently doing this with several individual MySQL statements and wish to improve the efficiency by reducing it to one MySQL statement.

Steps to complete are:

1. Retrieve the primary key and boolean enabled state for supplied sensor serial number from device table
2. Test if primary key exists and boolean enabled value is true, if either is no, then just exit.
3. If primary key exists and boolean enabled is true, then store the incoming data value and the primary key (identified by the above test) into another table named datain

Maybe below explains a little better what I am trying to do. I know this is not valid MySQL, just an example of what want.

```
`INSERT INTO mydb.datain(sensorpk,sensorvalue) values (pk from sensor serial in device table, 25.4) WHERE mydb.device.pk =  pk from sensor serial in device table AND mydb.device.enabled = TRUE;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reading your question differently than Stefan did: I believe you're saying you want to issue a single SQL statement as follows:

- You have the serial # of a device (which does not sound like it's the primary key), and the device data
- If the device is disabled, the data should not be inserted into your table.
- If the device is enabled, it should be inserted.

Using Stefan's dbfiddle as a starting point, I came up with this:

```
insert into datain (device_id, datain)
select device_id, @device_data
from device
where serialno = @serial_no
  and state <> 0 ;
```

My version of the dbfiddle is [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=c9dde79403046db2df35cbe9519bcbcc); it shows four insert attempts, two for enabled devices, with one for a disabled device and one for an invalid serial # in between. Only the data for the enabled devices that exist is added.

Quick explanation of how this works: You're starting with two know values, the serial number of a device (which uniquely identifies it), and the data that should (maybe) be inserted. We're simply selecting the `device_id` from the `device` table that matches your serial number, *and is enabled*. If the device matching your serial number is disabled, we'll get no rows back in the `SELECT`, and nothing will be inserted; we only insert the data if we find the serial number, *and* the device is enabled.

FYI: If you had a table with the serial numbers and device data, you could insert all the valid ones at once with:

```
insert into datain (device_id, datain)
select dev.device_id, data.device_data
from device dev
       INNER JOIN inbound_data data ON (dev.serialno = data.serial_no)
where dev.state <> 0 ;
```

Comment: I can only say "Excellent", than you very much. This is working exactly how I wanted it to. I don't quite fully understand HOW it works, but it does.  After a bit more thinking and trying to work out what this is doing, I think I understand it now. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Added a quick explanation of how it works - hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following SQL code will help you to find a solution.  The comments "-- step1, -- step 2" etc refer to your question. Dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=18459831910fe4b819acc090cbfafcff) , also tested with MySQL 5.5.

```
create table device (
  serialno int primary key
, dataval int
, state tinyint
);
-- use tinyint instead of bool 0 = false, non-zero = true
-- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html

insert into device (serialno, dataval, state)
values 
 (1,11,1),(2,22,0),(3,33,1),(4,44,0)
,(5,55,1),(6,66,0),(7,77,1),(8,88,0);

create table datain (
  id int auto_increment primary key
, device_serialno int references device(serialno)
, datain int
);
```

"Steps to complete" ... NOTICE: "step 3" contains both the SELECT and INSERT, as required (as one statement).  Steps 1 and 2 are just for "illustration".

```
-- step 1
select serialno, state from device;

-- find all devices and states (CASE - just to make the output more "readable")
select serialno
, state
, case 
    when state = 0 then 'disabled'
    else 'enabled'
  end state_
from device;

-- "supplied sensor serial number" 
set @id_ = 5;

-- step 2
select serialno, state 
from device
where serialno = @id_
  and state <> 0 ;

-- step 3
insert into datain (device_serialno, datain)
select serialno, dataval
from device
where serialno = @id_
  and state <> 0 ;
```

If you wanted to insert data from all enabled devices, you could maybe use something like ...

```
insert into datain (device_serialno, datain)
select serialno, dataval
from device
where state <> 0 ;
```